# How to add menu to tools in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I am quite new on developing extension for Visual Studio IDE.

I'm learning it from official documents of Microsoft.

However, I couldn't understand how to make new menu.

I have already added to tool but I'd like to add new menu that contains my tools.

In microsoft documents there are lots of things like groups, buttons and menus. However, I couldn't understand the hiearchy between them especially links with ID's.

Can someone explain how it works ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to make a top level menu, add a submenu to an existing menu, or just add a menu-item?